# Удаление через Iterator не влияет на саму коллекцию в классе

Tags: java, android, итераторы

Помогите разобраться почему так происходит.

```
    Iterator<Item> iterator = player.getItems().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            if (iterator.next().getType() == 4){
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
```

на входе **player.getItems()** имеет 3 объекта, 2 из которых удовлетворяют условию в цикле. После цикла **iterator** содержит 1 объект как и положено, а **player.getItems()** как было 3 так и осталось.
Итератор же должен был удалить в коллекции **player.getItems()** объекты удовлетворяющие условию? Что я не так делаю, помогите разобраться.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/223918/4291923 тут ответ на ваш вопрос

Comment: К сожалению я не нашел там ответа на вопрос почему удаление из итератора не удаляет из базовой коллекции :(

Comment: Что за метод `player.getItems()`? Скорее всего он возвращает копию коллекции, а не ссылку на оригинал.

Comment: Точно! Спасибо! блин, нужно было сразу глянуть же. Зато кучу статей прочитать успел - просветился :)

Answer (score 1):

**В java 8 можно удалять таким образом:**

```
player.getItems().get(i).removeIf()
```

Comment: for (Object o : objects){ o.removeIf(...) } отработает без ошибок получается?

Comment: @xWeb да, там уже все предусмотрено. Но единственное player.getItems() вам нужно до цикла записать в какую-то переменную.

Comment: спасибо, суть понял)

Comment: @xWeb если не запишите - проблема со счетчиками будет